# Is there a Scala command-line debugger?

Tags: scala

Is there a Scala command-line debugger (a la jdb)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old question, but here is sdb, which is a jdb clone written in Scala using the Ensime debugger api: https://github.com/ensime/scala-debugger/releases/tag/v1.1.0-M3

And the sbt plugin: https://github.com/ensime/scala-debugger/releases/tag/v1.1.0-M3-2

Answer (score 0):

Will the Scala Interpreter(REPL) to debug not be helpful ? A cooler way, to test your code could be through sbt REPL.

```
1. sbt
2. console
3. scala ( for Scala REPL ); [cntrl d] to get back to sbt REPL
4. compile
5. test, if you have unit-tests to test code
6. run If one has an object with a main method (or an object extending
   the trait App
```